# PDF files opens in Client and Office Web Apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps

We're running a SP2013 SP1 farm and Office Web Apps SP1. The PDF files stored in the document libraries behave rather strange.

All PDF files opens both in OWA and the native client application (Adobe reader). We have an other 2013 farm and this farm acts normal (opens in OWA).

I compared both environments and see a small difference, namely it's missing this action (for both internal as external zone):

```
Application     : WordPdf
Extension       : PDF
ProgId          :
Action          : mobileView
IsDefaultAction : False
ServerName      : {{OWA-SERVER}}
WopiZone        : internal-https
```

I'd tried to recreate a new spwopibinding for this type of application

```
Get-SPWOPIBinding –Application “WordPDF” | Remove-SPWOPIBinding -Confirm:$false

New-SPWOPIBinding –ServerName “Server.corp.Contoso.com” –Application “WordPDF”
```

But had no luck.. Does anyone know how to force PDF's to open in OWA?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We found the problem, the DOCICON.XML located in \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML on SharePoint Server was tempered with (might have been an update, according to MS).

This was the old value:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="icpdf.png" OpenControl="AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments" EditText="Adobe Acrobat or Reader X" />
```

We changed this with:

```
<Mapping Key="pdf" Value="icpdf.png" OpenControl=""/>
```

PDF's are opening in OWA again.